# Find the value of $\sin(B-A)$.

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

If $A$ is an acute angle whose tangent is $\frac{15}{8}$ and $B$ is and obtuse angle whose sine is $\frac{12}{13}$, find $\sin (B-A)$.

[Without calculators]

I suppose I gotta use this formula: $\sin B \cos A - \cos B \sin A$

Before that they asked me to find $\tan 2A$ which is $\frac{-240}{161}$ and $\cos 2B$ which is $\frac{-119}{169}$

But I can't understand how to proceed....help please!

Comment: You can look up double angle identities. Or note $tan(2x) = \frac{sin(2x)}{cos(2x)}$ and $sin(2x) = sin(x+x)$, $cos(2x) = cos(x+x)$.

Comment: @Batman : Could you type $\sin(2x)$ instead of $sin(2x)$ and similarly with $\cos$ and $\tan$?  That is the correct usage.  Not only does the backslash prevent italicization but it also provides correct spacing in things like $a\sin b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label a right triangle with one acute angle $A$. Since $\tan A = \dfrac{15}{8}$ you can label the opposite side with length $15$ and the adjacent side with length $8$. Then the hypotenuse has length $17$ so that $\sin A = \dfrac{15}{17}$ and $\cos A = \dfrac{8}{17}$.

For $B$, use $\sin^2 B + \cos^2 B = 1$. Since $B$ is obtuse, its cosine is negative. Thus $\cos B = - \dfrac{5}{13}$. Now use the formula for $\sin(B-A)$.

Comment: Or if you don't like diagrams, you could use $1+\tan^2(B) \equiv sec^2(B)$.

Comment: I guess it's perfect and clear. Thanks! @Umberto P.

Comment: okay...what answer do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for the "before that" part: $\tan(2A)\equiv\frac{2\tan(A)}{1-\tan^2(A)}$. You know that $\tan(A)=\frac{15}{8},$ so sub. this into the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use pythagurus theorem and solve for $SinB, cosB,CosA, SinA$. Then substitute the values in your formula $Sin(B-A)$, you will get the answer.